# MediaPlayer not working properly in Java

Tags: java, media-player

I have a question about Java related with the class `MediaPlayer` that is used for playing an introductory video. The point is that when running my application the video sometimes is played correctly and sometimes not, most of the times not. By saying that it is not played correctly I am referring that the audio is played but the image not. So I can conclude that `MediaPlayer` is not working properly.

Here is the code of my application:

```
/**
 * Main class of the application.
 */
public class Main{

  // Define the variable for the window of the game.
  public static JFrame window;

  // Define the variable for the introductory video.
  public static MediaPlayer video;

  /**
   * Main function of the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args){

    // Prevent the JavaFX toolkit from closing.
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    // Create the window of the game.
    window = new JFrame();

    // Set the title.
    window.setTitle("Chip");

    // Set the resolution as 1920 x 1280.
    window.setSize(1926,1343);

    // Set the location as in the middle of the screen.
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Set the operation when the window closes.
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Disable the maximization and resizable mode.
    window.setResizable(false);

    // Show the window.
    window.setVisible(true);

    // Show the introductory video.
    showVideo();

    // Pause the execution of the application for 30 seconds (duration of the introductory video).
    try{
      Thread.sleep(30000);
    }catch (InterruptedException interruptedException){
      interruptedException.printStackTrace();
    }

  }


  /**
   * Shows the introductory video.
   */
  public static void showVideo(){

    // Create the video panel and the JavaFX panel.
    JPanel panelVideo = new JPanel();
    JFXPanel panelJavaFX = new JFXPanel();

    // Set the size of the video panel as the resolution of the introductory video (1920 x 1080).
    panelVideo.setSize(1920,1080);

    // Set the location of the video panel as in the middle of the window of the game.
    int coordinateX = (window.getWidth() - panelVideo.getWidth() - window.getInsets().left - window.getInsets().right) / 2;
    int coordinateY = (window.getHeight() - panelVideo.getHeight() - window.getInsets().top - window.getInsets().bottom) / 2;
    panelVideo.setLocation(coordinateX,coordinateY);

    // Define the video file.
    String filename = "./media/video/introduction.mp4";
    video = new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File(filename).toURI().toString()));

    // Add the video to the JavaFX panel.
    panelJavaFX.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new MediaView(video))));

    // Add the JavaFX panel to the video panel.
    panelVideo.add(panelJavaFX);

    // Add the video panel to the window of the game.
    window.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    window.add(panelVideo);

    // Play the video.
    video.play();

  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using JavaFX? Because if you are, I'd recommend that you use MediaView to and not a panel to handle your MediaPlayer

Comment: Yes, I am using JavaFX. How would the code look like, then? I have no idea.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `video.play();` method directly after the initialization of your MediaPlayer, at least for me that seemed to fix it, i.e. :

```
video = new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File(filename).toURI().toString()));
video.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this question is:

I added the variable `panelJavaFX` (`JFXPanel`) directly to the variable `window` (`JFrame`), so I finally didn't use the intermediate variable `panelVideo` (`JPanel`).